# Is there any difference between causative constructions "Have + object + infinitive" and "Have + object + present participle"?

Tags: grammar, causatives

Two sentences:

- I will have the mechanic repair my car tomorrow.
- I will have the mechanic repairing my car tomorrow.

Is there any difference between them?

Comment: You can refer to the base form: to have someone **do** something. To make someone **do** something. You can look up: have, make and let.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you, I understand about make, let and have. I would like to gain a better understanding of whether the use of '-ing' influences the meaning of a sentence or if the infinitive has the same meaning

Comment: Rodrigo: it is not grammatical to use ing with any of these.

Comment: *I'll have the mechanic repairing the car in no time*. would be grammatical. But not with tomorrow. I'll have him playing the violin in no time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Causative verbs:

The causative verbs are: Let, Make, Have, Get, Help

These are followed by the bare form of the verb:

Make someone do something
Have someone do something   [see below: having]
Let someone do something
Help someone do something/help someone to do something [both are acceptable]

**have someone doing something**:
***To have someone doing something means to act in such a way as to cause someone to be occupied in doing something, usually a continuous activity.***

We had the kids playing football in the yard.

**Get someone to do something** [must have the **to infinitive]**

[expresso English](https://www.espressoenglish.net/causative-verbs-in-english-let-make-have-get-help/)

Comment: Disagree that it *must* be to-infinitive. Consider: "*Can I **get** my car **moving** using 5th gear instead of 1st gear?*", "*That chorus **got** the crowd **screaming***", "*You **got** traffic **moving** again*".

Comment: But that is not: get someone to do something. Get something verb+ing is a different meaning.

Comment: The OP's question is about the difference between "*have someone to-infinitive*" and "*have someone -ing*". It's not just about to-infinitive, nor just about the normal causitive function.

Comment: @gotube Yes, and for me, the second one is semantically ungrammatical. "I'll have the kids playing baseball in no time" but "will have x repairing y tomorrow" sounds like he is your employee. So, if he is, OK. Otherwise, no.

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean now and we agree on what's wrong, if not on the vocabulary to describe how it's wrong. I consider grammar and semantics to be entirely separate. To me, the grammar of the second sentence is good, but the intended meaning is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: @gotube Exactly. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The first, with infinitive, is the normal causitive meaning, in function roughly equivalent to, "*I'm going to drop my car off at the shop tomorrow*", (and then the mechanic will repair it some time after I drop it off, possibly tomorrow, but not necessarily).

The second, with present participle, means you will --at some time today or tomorrow-- ensure that tomorrow the mechanic will be working on your car. Here, the focus is when the mechanic will do the work -> tomorrow. This is an odd sentence that I can only imagine using when frustrated that a mechanic isn't working on your car, and you're determined to make them do so.

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation is very clear

Comment: I think the ing one is not really grammatical at all. make, have, let are followed by a bare form of the verb.

Comment: @Lambie The function is to cause something to be happening at a specific point in the future. Like, *This DJ will have the entire club dancing in minutes.*" The OP's sentence is an odd place to use it, but it's grammatical.

Comment: That dancing example is OK, but not the mechanic example. Your means: To have someone doing something means to act in such a way as to cause someone to be occupied in doing something, usually a continuous activity. So....

Comment: @Lambie The mechanic could likely spend more time repairing the car than the people in the club spend dancing. The main thing wrong with the second sentence may be that it's just plain weird.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, that's right. It would work sarcastically of course. "I'll have that mechanic repairing my car again tomorrow if he doesn't want to be sued". My neighbor had a bad oil leak in her Range Rover and was in a situation like that. The guy had to go two rounds to get the job done properly.

Comment: @Lambie That example is just about perfect. It also demonstrates what an unusual situation it must be that calls for such phrasing.

Comment: @Lambie Exactly what I explained in my second paragraph